# What can be done with Thunderbird data left behind after removing an e-mail account?

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

I know how to remove an e-mail account from Thunderbird.  However, after removing all my e-mail accounts from Thunderbird (under Linux), I discovered that my default Thunderbird profile still contains a lot of data (if not all of it) from the removed accounts.  For example, `ImapMail` subfolder takes 2.6 GB and seems to contain all the mail from removed accounts, and it contains several copies of one account which I had removed and set up several times.

Can this data left behind be accessed through Thunderbird interface in any way?  In particular, can I ask Thunderbird to remove it, or do I need to do it manually?  If I change my mind and decide to re-create one of the removed accounts in Thunderbird, can I instruct it to use the saved data instead of downloading it again?  If not, does it mean that this data is essentially lost, and this is a Thunderbird bug?  In this case, could you suggest any instructions for cleaning up this data manually?

This question would probably be more appropriate for [Mozilla community support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/get-community-support), but I do not want to register for just one question.  (It seems likely I will stop using Thunderbird soon.)

Comment: Maybe try clearing the cache in Preferences > Preferences > Advanced > Network & Disk Space

Comment: Thanks for an idea, but this didn't help.  Obviously, what i am talking about is regular account data and not cache.  My cache was limited to 350 MB by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274452) and it is supposed to be [fixed](https://hg.mozilla.org/comm-central/rev/d2345e14a58802e703ee9338e9890a494119bf5b) in Thunderbird 52.0.